# SyntaxError: expected 'else' after 'if' expression

Tags: python

```
df['comp_score'] = df['compound'].apply(lambda c: 'pos' if c >=0 'neu' if c ==0 else 'neg')

df.head()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkitJ.png)

I want to use a neutral sentiment but the result is an error like this. is the code wrong? please help

Comment: The `c >=0 'neu'` part of that expression makes no sense.  Both of those `if`s require a corresponding `else`, and I think the missing one belongs in the middle of the part I quoted.

Answer (score 3):

You left out an `else` so the first conditional expression isn't legal (the condition is followed by a random value, not a continuation of the conditional test or an `else` to introduce the third expression). Change:

```
'pos' if c >= 0 'neu' if c == 0 else 'neg'
```

to:

```
'pos' if c >= 0 else 'neu' if c == 0 else 'neg'
              # ^^^^ added
```

Note that even with fixed syntax, your logic makes no sense; the `c >= 0` will prevent the `c == 0` test from ever firing. You probably really wanted:

```
'pos' if c > 0 else 'neu' if c == 0 else 'neg'
         # ^ now just >, not >=
```

so you get `'pos'` only when `c` is strictly greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need two elses. Try:

```
'pos' if c >=0 else 'neu' if c ==0 else 'neg'
```

Except that now your code doesn't make sense. The value will
never be `'neu'` because `c >= 0` will include the `c == 0` case.

ternary if else expressions can quickly get ugly. Python aims for simplicity, so you might do something with smaller expressions like:

```
def describe_number(c):
    if c < 0: return 'neg'
    if c > 0: return 'pos'
    return 'neu'
```

and use `describe_number(c)` in your code.

It's better to use this code with integer values, not floating point. With floating point numbers this code may not behave the way you expect due to [floating point errors](https://blog.penjee.com/what-are-floating-point-errors-answered/).